# wp e-commerce plugin payment gateway module

Tags: wordpress, plugin

I've installed the [klarna](http://integration.klarna.com/en/modules/wp-e-commerce) payment gateway plugin

> Unpacking the package…
>
> Installing the plugin…
>
> Plugin installed successfully.

and when I click "Activate plugin" appears this message "The plugin does not have a valid header."
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is presented by WordPress when a plugin is missing some [standard information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information) that identifies it, what it does, etc. But that's not the problem here.

From the fact you got that error, it seems you tried to install the archive as a regular WP plugin, but it's not a plugin at all. It's a module for WP-Ecommerce and has an entirely [different installation process](http://integration.klarna.com/modules/step-by-step?step=3&module=9).

Comment: Thanks, but now I have another problem, after I've installed this my wordpress site doesn't work (appears a blank page)

Comment: If the developer's own installation docs result in an unusable site, you need to start talking to them. Something's just broken.